# how to add limit of users in my django channels chat room

Tags: django, websocket, django-channels

i wish to had not more than 2 users limit in my chat room

```
from channels.consumer import SyncConsumer,AsyncConsumer
from channels.exceptions import StopConsumer
from asgiref.sync import async_to_sync

class MySyncConsumer(SyncConsumer):
    def websocket_connect(self, event):
        chat_channel_name = self.scope['url_route']['kwargs']['channelname']
        async_to_sync (self.channel_layer.group_add)(self.chat_channel_name,self.channel_name)
            self.send({
            'type':'websocket.accept'
            })
```

I want to add limited number of users in my chat room

Comment: Your application needs to support a RoomManagerConsumer that looks at a value in MySyncConsumer which is incremented every time RoomManagerConsumer sends a join command to a user